# When clearing textbox on UI the converter doesn't trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I'm adding value or changing it in a textbox, converter triggers every time. When I remove/clear value the converter never trigger. Also after saving empty filed it actually save the value it was there previously.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FemaleCT, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="100">
      <TextBox.Background>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource inToleranceHighlightsConverter}">
               <Binding Path="FemaleCT"></Binding>
               <Binding ElementName="MF" Path="Text"></Binding> 
               <Binding ElementName="MF_LowTolerance" Path="Text"></Binding>
               <Binding ElementName="MF_HighTolerance" Path="Text"></Binding>
               <Binding ElementName="SampleEnabled" Path="Text"></Binding>
          </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

This could be important, the data value FemaleCT is nullable decimal and is part of ObservableCollection.

```
public ObservableCollection<MouldCTModel> ctMeasurements
    {
        get { return _ctMeasurements; }
        set { _ctMeasurements = value; this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ctMeasurements)); CanSignScreen(); }
    }
```

Is this normal behaviour or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is binding a decimal to a string property. string.empty cannot be converted to a decimal, so the binding fails and the property is not updated. Because the property doesn't change, the converter is not fired, and the object still has it's old value.

I find it best to wrap numbers, dates, etc in string properies:

```
    private string femaleCT;

    public string FemaleCT
    {
        get
        {
            return this.femaleCT;
        }

        set
        {
            this.femaleCT = value;

            decimal temp;
            if (decimal.TryParse(value, out temp))
            {
                this.model.FemaleCT = temp;
            }

            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and then write the converter to take a string, and it can decide what to do when the string is blank, or otherwise not a valid value.

This method also allows you to validate the string value. Validating the model isn't sufficient, because it is only updated when the value is a valid number.